# Global timeout handler in expect?

Tags: expect

I've got an expect script that looks a bit like this:

```
set timeout 15
spawn someprocess
expect "a line"
expect "another line"
expect "some other line"
```

Essentially, it's waiting until these lines appear. There are no actions to be taken.

I don't want to write the following for every line that I'm looking for:

```
expect {
    "a line" {}
    timeout { exit 1 }
}
```

I want `expect` to return a non-zero status code (i.e. in `$?`) if it times out at any point. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can setup an `expect_before` line that is run "in parallel" with any later expect commands to test for timeout. Just add after your `spawn` command

```
expect_before timeout { exit 1 }
```

If you want to error out if the spawned process exits, you can combine them as follows:

```
expect_before {
    timeout { exit 1 }
    eof { exit 1 }
}
```

Comment: Note that I had to also add `expect_after eof { exit 1 }` to cause an error if the process quit before outputting the expected text.